# How to foreach and eval function in Makefile work?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, android-source

I'm trying to understand Makefile syntax and Makefile system of AOSP. But, it is difficult to a beginner like me. I understand how fereach function work but dont understand when is used with eval function like below. Can someone explain the piece of Makefile code below ? how it work step by step and the output of every step ? the final value of `all_product_configs` variable ? Thanks all so much !

```
all_product_configs := $(call get-product-makefiles,\
    $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/AndroidProducts.mk)
```

and this is definition of `get-product-makefiles` function :

```
define get-product-makefiles
$(sort \
  $(foreach f,$(1), \
    $(eval PRODUCT_MAKEFILES :=) \
    $(eval LOCAL_DIR := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(f)))) \
    $(eval include $(f)) \
    $(PRODUCT_MAKEFILES) \
   ) \
  $(eval PRODUCT_MAKEFILES :=) \
  $(eval LOCAL_DIR :=) \
 )
endef
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` takes its argument and evaluates it as Makefile syntax -- definitions of variables and rules, and any other GNUmake syntax -- and expands to nothing (an empty string)

`foreach` takes its 3rd argument and repeats it once for each word in the 2nd argument, with 1st argument being defined as the corresponding word each time.  The result is that (big) string.

`call` takes its first argument as the name of a variable and expands that variable with `$(1)`, `$(2)`, etc set to the other arguments of the `call`

So from the top, you expand `get-product-makefiles` with `$(1)` set to `$(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/AndroidProducts.mk`  That is actually the 2nd arg of a foreach, and is onlye one word, so the `foreach` will expand the 3rd arg once, with `$(f)` set to that string (`$(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/AndroidProducts.mk`).  So that is just

```
$(eval PRODUCT_MAKEFILES :=) \
$(eval LOCAL_DIR := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/AndroidProducts.mk))) \
$(eval include $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/AndroidProducts.mk) \
$(PRODUCT_MAKEFILES) \
```

So it runs those evals which defines those variables (`PRODUCT_MAKEFILES` and `LOCAL_DIR`) and then includes the other makefile (which presumables defines `PRODUCT_MAKEFILES` to be something non-empty, probably appending stuff to it).  It then expands to whatever that is, followed by the last two `eval` commands whic clear those two variables and expand to nothing.  So the net result will be just whatever `$(PRODUCT_MAKEFILES)` was defined as in the AndroidProducts.mk while that variable itself is not actually set any more.  It then sorts that (the `sort` command -- which incidentally deletes duplicated words after sorting), and that is what the whole thing ends up as -- and that is what `all_product_configs` gets set  to.

This would be more interesting if there were mulitple makefiles in the `call` command.  Then it would end up reading all of them and pulling in all the things they define in `PRODUCT_MAKEFILES`, concatenating and sorting the lot.